# Angular how to pass information down a component between tags

Tags: angular, components

I mean like

```
<app-select-component><p>Hello world</p></app-select-component>
```

I forgot how this technique called, and having a hard time describing it to google....

Comment: It is called "transclusion" in AngularJS and "content projection" in Angular https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed, I can approve the answer if you'd like.